# Multiple Optional ForeignKeys in Django

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys

Before I start: My understanding of Django is at a beginner Level and i could not find adequate help through google.

I'll start with an example:

```
class Player(models.Model):
  ...


class Tournament(models.Model):
  ...
  first_place = models.ForeignKey(Player)
  second_place = models.ForeignKey(...)
  third_place = models.ForeignKey(...)
```

My problem is: there are multiple people in first place, second place and so on. How can I realize the model in a way which lets me add my own number of Players every time?

I already tried `ManyToMany` instead of `ForeignKey` but then I get an Error in the admin menu when i try to save a `Tournament` Object stating that there has to be an ID present for the Object even when I do not select any `Player`s to be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if I understand the question correctly, but if you want to make `ForeignKey`s optional and also want to add multiple `Player`s, you could use `ManyToManyField` and set `null` and `blank`, both `True`:

```
class Tournament(...):
    ...
    first_place = models.ManyToManyField(Player, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This would solve your problem you can now freely add each and any place to each player. The .count() function in your view can get the number of objects for the selected players. No need for a manytomanyfield when you can just assign a place to an object by the user with every user now being able to have unlimited places in each category, if I understand what your trying to do here. Comment if you need more help.

```
Class FirstPlace(models.Model):
     first = models.ForeignKey(Player)

Class SecondPlace(models.Model):
     second = models.ForeignKey(Player)

 Class ThirdPlace(models.Model):
     third = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```